# Fazer contagem de uma coluna pl/sql

Tags: sql, pl-sql, count

Estou tentando fazer a contagem de uma coluna (minutos) como está na query:

```js
SELECT distinct b.nr_atendimento
        ,to_char(dt_prescricao,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') Prescricao
        ,to_char(a.dt_atualizacao,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') Atualizacao
        ,trunc( mod(mod(a.dt_atualizacao-dt_prescricao,1)*24,1)*60 ) as Minutos
FROM    result_laboratorio a,
        prescr_procedimento c,
        prescr_medica b
WHERE  Trunc( LAST_DAY( b.dt_prescricao )) = Last_Day(:MES_REF)
    AND c.nr_prescricao  = a.nr_prescricao(+) 
    AND c.nr_sequencia = a.nr_seq_prescricao(+) 
    AND c.nr_prescricao  = b.nr_prescricao 
    AND b.cd_estabelecimento = '1'
    AND a.dt_atualizacao IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY nr_atendimento desc
```

Já estou somando as horas e tirando os minutos durante os atendimento, porém preciso contar o total de minutos.

Resultado:

atend.  Pedido              Resultado           Minutos

1727336 21/05/2021 08:42:00 21/05/2021 09:50:21 68

1727336 21/05/2021 08:42:00 21/05/2021 09:50:30 68

```
                             Total minutos: 136
```

Quero que a minha query faça a soma total

Comment: Ja estou somando as horas e tirando os minutos durante os atendimento, porém preciso somar o tatal de minutos

Comment: Qual o sistema gerenciador de banco de dados? Qual resultado está retornando? Qual o resultado esperado?

Comment: Resultado: 
atend.      Pedido                             Resultado                       Minutos    
1727336 21/05/2021 08:42:00 21/05/2021 09:50:21 68
1727336 21/05/2021 08:42:00 21/05/2021 09:50:30 68
                                                                 Total minutos:        136
Quero que a minha query faça a soma total dos minutos

Comment: Qual o banco de dados está utilizando?

Comment: pl sql oracle developer

Answer (score 0):

O resultado da sua query, não bate com a query de exemplo.

Na query não tem o campo atendimento, mas no resultado sim, de qualquer forma entendo que o que você precisa é uma query semelhante a query abaixo, caso realmente a query exemplo esteja errado por favor, post a query correta:

```
SELECT ATENDIMENTO  AS ATENDIMENTO,
       SUM(X.HORAS)   AS TOTAL_HORAS,
       SUM(X.MINUTOS) AS TOTAL_MINUTOS
FROM (

SELECT ATENDIMENTO, 
      START_DATE,
      END_DATE, 
      TRUNC( 24* (END_DATE - START_DATE))           AS HORAS,
      ( MOD(MOD(END_DATE - START_DATE,1)*24,1)*60 ) AS MINUTOS
 FROM T
 
) X
GROUP BY ATENDIMENTO
```

Comment: Obrigado por informar sobre a query, fiz a edição, porém não consigo chegar para somar o total de minutos.

Comment: Você precisa somente retornar o valor total em minutos?